# Complex Regex is not validating all repetitions of one specific rule

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need help to validate a field using regex. It will run in Postgres 9.5.

**The rules are**

- The string must contain all seven services: Oil, Wiper blades, Air filter, Tires, Battery, Brake, Antifreeze
- **All services must have the operation hours, and the accepted values are HH[:MM]{am|pm}-HH[:MM]{am|pm}, or the literals ”working hours”, ”after hours”, ”not available”** (this is the rule that I couldn't find the solution)
- It is case insensitive, and the spaces should be irrelevant.
- The services as separated by a pipe, and the service and working hours are separated by a colon

I did the regex:

```
^(?=.*(Oil))(?=.*(Wiper blades))(?=.*(Air filter))(?=.*(Tires))(?=.*(Battery))(?=.*(Brake))(?=.*(Antifreeze))(?=.*(\s{0,}(1{0,1}[0-2]|[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){0,1}\s{0,}([ap]m)\s{0,}-\s{0,}(1{0,1}[0-2]|[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){0,1}\s{0,}([ap]m)|working hours|after hours|not availabl)).+
```

This part of the regex is validating only one sequence, not all seven sequences.

```
(?=.*(\s{0,}(1{0,1}[0-2]|[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){0,1}\s{0,}([ap]m)\s{0,}-\s{0,}(1{0,1}[0-2]|[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){0,1}\s{0,}([ap]m)|working hours|after hours|not availabl))
```

Example of good string

```
Oil:8AM-10PM|Wiper blades:8 AM -10 PM|Air filter:8AM-10pm|Tires:8AM-10PM|Battery:8AM-10PM|Brake:8AM-9PM|Antifreeze:not available
```

Example of bad strings

```
Oil:8AM-10PM|Wiper blades:8AM-10PM|Air filter:8AM-10PM|Tires:8AM-10PM|Battery:8AM-10PM|Brake:8AM-9PM|Antifreeze:fsdfdsfs

Oil:8AM-10PM|Wiper blades:8AM-10PM|Air filter:8AM|Tires:8AM-10PM|Battery:8AM-10PM|Brake:8AM-9PM|Antifreeze:

Oil:8AM-10PM|Wiper blades:8AM-10PM|Air filter:8AM-10PM|Tires:8AM-10PM|Battery:|Brake:|Antifreeze:8AM-9PM

Oil:8AM-10PM|Wiper blades:8AM-10PM
```

Do someone have any idea what is missing to validate the seven occurrences?

Comment: You need to add that pattern to each lookahead and the pattern will become huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made another regex that works :

```
^(((oil|Air\ filter|Wiper\ blades|Tires|Battery|Brake|Antifreeze):((((\d{1,2})((A|P)M)(-?)){2})|(not available))(\|?)){7})$
```

How ever, this regex does not take counts of repetition. Which mean, you could have Oil two time it will still works. 
[I've create a regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bNEHW3/2) if you wish to tests more cases.